# Get notified if a file is NOT modified in a document library in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I wonder if it is possible to get a notification from SharePoint Online if a file from my document library is **NOT** modified/updated at a specific date/time using Power Automate.

Can anyone advise please.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you could probably do something that runs on a schedule that compares the modified date to some other date. If the modified date is less than the comparison date, send an email. If you could add a bit more detail to your question, it'd certainly help point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can create a scheduled Power automate flow & compare the modified date with current date (or as per your requirements date) using expressions & condition action. Then based on condition, you can send an email to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Ganesh said, a daily recurrence flow with a condition check on the modified date seems to be a good option for you. You can set the modified date to compare with the created date or a specified date set by you. Here are examples for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/schedule-power-automaton-ms-flow-to-send-a-daily-mail-requesting-wfh

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Has-a-file-been-Modified/td-p/134780

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Building-a-flow-to-check-that-a-document-was-updated-today-using/td-p/69391

Comment: Many thanks to you all. Will deep dive into your solution and hopefully it will work for me.

Comment: Hope it works for you. And just comment if you have any question. If you get it done, please accept the reply as answer.